# Maximum match length of a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

What is the easiest way to determine the maximum match length of a regular expression?

Specifically, I am using Python's [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module.

E.g. for `foo((bar){2,3}|potato)` it would be 12.

Obviously, regexes using operators like `*` and `+` have theoretically unbounded match lengths; in those cases returning an error or something is fine. Giving an error for regexes using the `(?...)` extensions is also fine.

I would also be ok with getting an approximate upper bound, as long as it is always greater than the actual maximum length, but not *too* much greater.

Comment: That will be difficult. For example, the regex: `^(?!a{5,10}).*(?<=(aaaa|aaaaa))$` contains a `.*` but will only match four `a`'s due to "look-around" restrictions.

Comment: @Bart: that's not a valid regex in Python. your look-behind has variable length.

Comment: I've updated the question, I don't need support for `(?...)`.

Comment: Isn't the maximum match for the above 9 characters?  Did you mean `foo((bar){2,3}|potato)`?

Comment: Bonus points if anyone proves me wrong, but I don't think you're going to find a way to do this that doesn't involve either parsing the regex yourself or modifying the Python source, neither of which are very pleasant options.  The Python re module simply doesn't support introspection.

Comment: @SilentGhost, well, then change `(?<=(aaaa|aaaaa))` into 
`((?<=aaaa)|(?<=aaaaa))` to get the same result. But I see @adw doesn't need to account for look-arounds.

Comment: Do be careful--sre_parse isn't a public, documented API.  It's not explicitly a private one, or it'd be `_sre_parse`, but watch out if you're depending heavily on it.  It's probably the best option available, anyway.

Comment: @adw: Perhaps post your solution (using `getwidth`) as the accepted answer. I think it is superior to my answer, especially since it works on the too-long-to-enumerate `r'\w{1,10}'`.

Comment: @unutbu: Alright, if you'd prefer. I have to wait two days to accept my own answer though. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, I think. Thanks to unutbu for pointing me to `sre_parse`!

```
import sre_parse

def get_regex_max_match_len(regex):
    minlen, maxlen = sre_parse.parse(regex).getwidth()
    if maxlen >= sre_parse.MAXREPEAT: raise ValueError('unbounded regex')
    return maxlen
```

Results in:

```
>>> get_regex_max_match_len('foo((bar){2,3}|potato)')
12
>>> get_regex_max_match_len('.*')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in get_regex_max_match_len
ValueError: unbounded regex
```

Answer (score 6):

Using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)'s [invRegex](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/invRegex.py) module:

```
import invRegex
data='foo(bar{2,3}|potato)'    
print(list(invRegex.invert(data)))
# ['foobarr', 'foobarrr', 'foopotato']    
print(max(map(len,invRegex.invert(data))))
# 9
```

Another alternative is to use `ipermute` from [this module](http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg125198.html).

```
import inverse_regex
data='foo(bar{2,3}|potato)'
print(list(inverse_regex.ipermute(data)))
# ['foobarr', 'foobarrr', 'foopotato']
print(max(map(len,inverse_regex.ipermute(data))))
# 9
```

Comment: The latter falls apart on such a simple expression as `\w{1,10}`.  It does suggest how to do this properly, though, using the `sre_parse` module, and the ipermute code is a good starting point.  I'm not sure whether sre_parse is a public API, though; it doesn't seem to be documented, so be careful.